# Input vs Output Event Binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components, angular5, typescript-decorator

I'm looking for an argument on why using `@Output` for events is better than passing an `@Input` function in Angular 2+.

**Using `@Input`:**

Parent Template:

```
<my-component [customEventFunction]=myFunction></my-component>
```

Inside parent-component.ts:

```
myFunction = () => {
  console.log("Hello world")
}
```

Inside my-component.ts

```
@Input() customEventFunction: Function;

someFunctionThatTriggersTheEvent() {
  this.customEventFunction();
}
```

**Using `@Output`:**

Parent Template:

```
<my-component (onCustomEvent)=myFunction()></my-component>
```

Inside parent-component.ts:

```
myFunction() {
  console.log("Hello world")
}
```

Inside my-component.ts

```
@Output() onCustomEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

someFunctionThatTriggersTheEvent() {
  this.onCustomEvent.emit();
}
```

Both achieve the same goal, but I think that the `@Output` method is more typical from what I've seen in other Angular packages. One could argue that with an Input, you can check to see if the function exists if the event should only be triggered conditionally.

Thoughts?

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Why would you use Output over Input for event binding and vice versa?

Comment: One reason would be that many subscribers can handle the Output event, while only one handler can be supplied for the Input property.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Hmm, I hadn't thought about that. I'd be happy to accept that as an answer with a little more elaboration if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantages of @Output event binding:

1. Defining an event with @Output makes it clear that it expects callback methods to handle the event, using the standard Angular mechanism and syntax.
2. Many event handlers can subscribe to the @Ouptut event. On the other hand, if you define an @Input property that accepts a callback function, only one event handler can be registered; assigning a second event handler would disconnect the first one. To make a parallel with standard DOM event handlers, the @Input callback function binding is similar to setting `onmousemove="doSomething()"` while the @Output event binding is more like calling `btn.addEventListener("mousemove", ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

@Sajeetharan's answer actually isn't quite correct: there *is* a significant functional difference: the execution context. Consider this scenario:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: `<button (click)="runFn()">Click Me</button>`,
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  @Input() public fn: any;

  public runFn(): void {
    this.fn();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<app-example [fn]="myFn"></app-example>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public state = 42;

  // Using arrow syntax actually *will* alert "42" because
  // arrow functions do not have their own "this" context.
  //
  // public myFn = () => window.alert(this.state);

  public myFn(): void {
    // Oops, this will alert "undefined" because this function
    // is actually executed in the scope of the child component!
    window.alert(this.state);
  }
}
```

This actually makes it pretty awkward to use `@Input()` properties to pass functions. At the very least it breaks the principle of least surprise and can introduce sneaky bugs.

Of course there are scenarios where maybe you don't need a context. For example, maybe you have a searchable list component that allows complex data as items and need to pass a `fnEquals` function so the search can determine whether the search input text matches an item. However, these cases are typically better handled by more composable mechanisms (content projection etc.) which increases reusability.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! We have used @Input event binding in a few places in our app and I haven't been able to figure out why the arrow functions were necessary for the scope. Can I ask why, since the arrow functions have no "this" context, that they have access to the context of the parent component instead of the child?

Comment: Arrow functions not defining their own "this" means that they get it from the enclosing execution context, which is where they are defined and independent of how they are called (normal functions can be bound to a specific "this"). The description section of the MDN article on arrow functions discusses this in detail.

Answer (score 2):

There is basically **`no differences`** in functionality, but

(i)When you use **`@input`** you get advantage of using **`@Input`** is that we can define the type and whether it is private or public

(ii)As **`@ConnorsFan`** mentioned in the comment, advantage of using **`@Ouput`** is many subscribers can handle the Output event, while only one handler can be supplied for the **`@Input`** property.